# How to randomly choose operators?

Tags: java

```
public class Operator{
    public int add(int a, int b){
        return a+b;
    }
    public int multiply(int a, int b){
        return a*b;
    }
    public int minus(int a, int b){
        return a-b;
    }
    public int divide(int a, int b){
        return a/b;
    }
}
int a = 1 + random.nextInt(19);
int b = 1 + random.nextInt(19);
int x = random.nextInt[2];
Operator[] operators = {add(),minus(),multiply()};
System.out.println("Question " + (i+1) +":\n " + "What is " + a + " operators[x] " + b + "?");
int answer = in.nextInt();
int solution = operators[x](a,b);
```

trying to pick to random numbers then either add multiply or divide them.`int solution = operators[x](a,b);` I realise this is rubbish. Is there anyway to randomly pick a function (method?) from an array then input to integers?

I know I could do this using if else statements like 
if x=1 add 
if x=2 multiply and so on
but I was hoping for a more sophisticated way
thanks

Comment: I don't think you need to be concerned about *sophistication* for this kind of code. Remember the KISS principle.

Comment: I more meant shorter rather than longer =)

Answer (score 5):

These simplest way is a `switch` statement. Assuming `static` methods:

```
final int solution;
switch (x) {
    case 0: solution = add(a, b);      break;
    case 1: solution = multiply(a, b); break;
    case 2: solution = subtract(a, b); break;
    case 3: solution = divide(a, b);   break;
    default: throw new Error();
}
```

Or a chain of conditional operators:

```
int solution =
    x==0 ? add(a, b)      :
    x==1 ? multiply(a, b) :
    x==2 ? subtract(a, b) :
         ? divide(a, b)   ;
```

The 'clever' approach is to use lambda expressions.

```
interface Operator {
    int op(int a, int b);
}
Operator[] ops = {
    (a, b) -> a + b,
    (a, b) -> a * b,
    (a, b) -> a - b,
    (a, b) -> a / b,
};
// ...
int solution = ops[x].op(a,b);
```

Alternatively, an `enum` could give you a name and operator together.

Comment: Note: your `Operator` interface has a standard counterpart: [`IntBinaryOperator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/IntBinaryOperator.html). Perhaps worth using that instead?

Comment: Good one. Just a suggestion that you can also use yield feature now in switch case.

Comment: @AndyTurner There is. But there's a finite number of those. Here I prefer a specific interface.

Comment: @AmanChhabra Or new form `switch` label. I had to make sure, but yes, not a preview feature in 14. But actually you'd probably want a name as well, which would require a traditional switch.

Comment: thanks I'll probably go with the first one as im a noob. another way I tried was to do this `String[] operators = {"+","-","*"};` then `a + "operators[random.nextInt[2]]" + b`. then some how cgange it to get an integer answer. would it be possible to do it this way

Comment: also why do you need to say the `solution` is `final`

Comment: @HenryGarrett You can place an assignment to a `name` variable next to the `solution`. / It needn't be `final`, but it does ensure that the variable is assigned exactly once.

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.Random; 

public class generateRandom{ 

    public static void main(String args[]) 
    { 
        // create instance of Random class 
        Random rand = new Random(); 

        // Generate random integers in range 0 to 3
        int result = rand.nextInt(4);
        switch (result)
        {
           case 0:
           //Java code for add(...)
           ;
           case 1:
           //Java code for multiply(...)
           ;
           case 2:
           //Java code for minus(...)
           ;
           case 3:
           //Java code for divide(...)
           ;
           default:
           //Java code what for ever you want
           ;
         }
    }

}
```

Comment: Note that this code would never choose the divide branch.